# How to reset List based on Map priority

Tags: java, java-stream

In Java, I've List and Map which holds similar parameter to lookup based on location fields and reset the List based on Priority.

How can we do it?

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo {

    private Map<Integer, DataConfig> getPriorityConfig() {
        // Here 1, 2... etc are priorities
        Map<Integer, DataConfig> MAP = new HashMap<>();
        MAP.put(1, new DataConfig("E", "3333"));
        MAP.put(2, new DataConfig("E", "1111"));
        MAP.put(3, new DataConfig("E", "5555"));
        MAP.put(4, new DataConfig("E", "2222"));
        MAP.put(5, new DataConfig("E", "4444"));
        return MAP;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
                new Student(4, "E4444", "John"),
                new Student(2, "E2222", "Mike"),
                new Student(1, "E1111", "Jane"),
                new Student(3, "E3333", "Victoria")
        );

        //  Arrange List based on Priority and create new List, output should be
        // here E3333 has priority-1, E1111 has priority-2, E5555 has priority-3 etc
        List<Student> newStudents = Arrays.asList(
                new Student(3, "E3333", "Victoria"),
                new Student(1, "E1111", "Jane"),
                new Student(2, "E2222", "Mike"),
                new Student(4, "E4444", "John")
        );
        // For me its  very important to processed based on priority only
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class DataConfig {
        private String type;
        private String location;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Student {
        private int id;
        private String location;
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: If you want to look up the priority for a location then the location should be the key in the Map with the priority as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented logic like below:

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
                new Student(4, "E4444", "John"),
                new Student(2, "E2222", "Mike"),
                new Student(1, "E1111", "Jane"),
                new Student(3, "E3333", "Victoria")
        );

        Map<Integer, DataConfig> priorityConfig = getPriorityConfig();
        Map<String, Integer> MAP = new HashMap<>();
        // location and Pri
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, DataConfig> entry : priorityConfig.entrySet()) {
            MAP.put(entry.getValue().type + entry.getValue().location, entry.getKey());
        }

        Map<Integer, Student> integerStudentMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Student s: students) {
            Integer integer = MAP.get(s.getLocation());
            integerStudentMap.put(integer, s);
        }
        Map<Integer, Student> collect = integerStudentMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(comparingByKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (e1, e2) -> e2));
        System.out.println(collect);

        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>(collect.values());
        System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: DataConfig's location object doesn't have E prefix and hence we're using + to perform lookup

Comment: Yes, I am sorry about typo, but yes thats the case. In my project I am doing something very complex logic for trade

Comment: Then, you don’t need this `integerStudentMap`. You can use `List<Student> list = students.stream() .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> MAP.get(s.getLocation())) .toList();` Or sort the original list in-place: `students .sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> MAP.get(s.getLocation()));`

Comment: Hey, would be good if you can add your logic as answer to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, there should be a map matching locations to their priorities (the opposite of what you actually have). Something like this:

```java
Map<String, Integer> locationPriorities = new HashMap<>();
locationPriorities.put("E1111", 1);
locationPriorities.put("E2222", 2);
// etc...
```

or if you retrieve the mapping from somewhere else, you could still convert it to the format you want:

```java
Map<String, Integer> locationPriorities =
    getPriorityConfig().entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .collect(toMap(e -> e.getValue().location, e -> e.getKey()));
```

---

Once you have the mapping above the sorting becomes pretty straightforward.

You can either collect a new sorted list:

```java
List<Student> newStudents =
    students.stream()
            .sorted(comparing(s -> locationPriorities.get(s.location)))
            .collect(toList());
```

or sort the existing list in-place:

```java
students.sort(comparing(s -> locationPriorities.get(s.location)));
```

---

Make sure to import these static methods (or use the qualified calls instead):

```java
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```